# Rails queries - measure performance and rescue heavy query if it takes too long

Tags: mysql, ruby, performance, performance-testing, database-performance

I have some heavy queries in my Rails app. What would be the best way for me to:

- report how much time the query is taking if it's above certain value (we use Rollbar, so it can just alert in it)
- kill the query if needed

I'm running my queries in production console but the information is insufficient since there is caching

`User.includes(posts: :comments).where(status: :active).references(:comments)`

and my users table is 10 million

I'm getting an alert / exception with message:
"Query X has ran xxxxxx ms"

Comment: You might want to implement your own [`timeout`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html). What are you aiming for? Fining slow queries to optimize them? Just "protect" the app from long-running requests?

Comment: You should also use `find_in_batches` if you _must_ run these huge queries

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With those, we might be able to figure out why it is slow and propose and SQL solution.  Then you can figure out how to get Rails to achieve that.